# React : Material Ui's TreeItem not working properly

Tags: reactjs, image, material-ui, treeview

More specifically I'm talking about the 'icon' prop.
According to the documentation(https://material-ui.com/api/tree-item/) every TreeItem has a prop that allows you to insert an icon next to the label.
In my case, here is what happens:
[showing text instead of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMbyr.png)

[using it in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qevLU.png)

To be mentioned is that I'm importing the image correctly. It's not working with direct links either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because icon property is a Node, so you might want to declare it like this:                
  `<TreeItem icon={<Plus/>} />`

Comment: Not working, in fact this throws a big error. Thanks for the response though